# Vector3.Lerp and world / screen coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would need some suggestions if possible.
I have a `new plane()` on which I draw shapes with the mouse and I display them with gizmos lines. Every new point (Vector3) inserted I visualize it with `Gizmos.DrawCube`(). During the drawing I can through my Editor add a new point between two existing points. Since i want that the new point is inserted halfway between the two extreme points with `Vector3.Lerp`, setting the float parameter to 0.5f, I get the correct position. The problem is that if the line is not "horizontal" (the two points on the same x-axis), the new inserted point does not "seem" to the center. If the line is very deep (high Z difference between two points) the inserted point overlaps (apparently) the furthest point. So I would like to find a value for the Lerp float that allows me to see the point inserted as the center between the two points although not really central. So I thought of converting the coordinates from World to Screen, finding the center and converting them back to World.

```
Vector3 previousSpot = new Vector3(); // first point
Vector3 currentSpot = new Vector3(); // second point
Vector3 previousSpotToScreen = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(previousSpot);
Vector3 currentSpotToScreen = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(currentSpot);
Vector3 insertionSpot = Vector3.Lerp(previousSpotToScreen, currentSpotToScreen, 0.5f);
Vector3 insertionSpotToWorld = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(insertionSpot);
```

but the value obtained is incorrect.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: Did you try to simply use `(vectorA + vectorB) * 0.5f` instead of lerp? The main problem is that WorldToScreen loses one dimension! The local forward. `ScreenToWorld` takes a Vector3 since in the Z component **you** have to define how far away from the camera the point should be... As said don't convert forth and back between screen coordinates but rather simply use `(previousSpot + currentSpot ) * 0.5f`

Comment: Btw a sidenote: You know that everything related to `Gizmos` will only be visible in the Scene View and not in the final GameView / rendered image. The UnityEditor namespace is enterily stripped off in a build anyway.

Comment: That the center point apparently overlaps the further point is due to perspective so if you really want it to be Central to the users perspective yes you somehow would have to convert it to screen coordinates but it might still be an issue to find out the desired depth of the point ...

Comment: @derHugo Yes, my asset is a full-fledged editor, it doesn't have to be compiled. What puzzles me is that if I convert the two Vector3 with WorldToScreenPoint I get: Starting vector3 (-1.0, 1.0, -7.1 and -0.8, 1.0, -5.6), Vector3 obtained after the conversion (431.5, 72, 3.0 and 553.5, 178, 4.5). It would seem that somehow the Z axis is being maintained. If I then convert the two "Screen" vectors back to "World" with ScreenToWorldPoint they are exactly the same as the starting ones. It would therefore seem that the conversion works in both directions without losing depth. [continue]

Comment: If I apply Lerp between the two vectors I get that the user's perspective is correct, that is, the added point seems central but looking at scene view it is actually offset. Maybe there is a slight correction to be applied but I'm trying them all ... adding the two vectors and dividing them by 0.5 would not seem to work.

Comment: sorry, adding the two vectors and multiplying them by 0.5f seems to return the same value as lerp

Comment: Oh sorry honestly I was convinced that WorldToScreenPoint returns a Vector2 .. didn't know it actually preserves a depth information, my bad :) The problem ofcourse: In this case it makes no sense to use it since then it doesn't fix the perspective issue caused by exactly that depth difference ^^ I don't think you can fix this with a different value for Lerp, 0.5 is for the center it just doesn't seem so. Maybe you could add some graphics of how you want it to look like.

Comment: Adding a float slider in the Editor I did some tests and I saw that with a deep line up to about 260 on the Z axis the correct value to show the point in the center would be about 0.01f (or 0.99f if the direction is opposite ). Or with a depth of 30 around 0.77. There should be a way of calculating the right value, a simple proportion is not applicable.

Comment: Well it totally depends on the positions of your points in the perspective field of view the effect will also vary depending on e.g. where they are on the views X axis.